# nested fragment java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am using nested fragment. my codes as following:

```
 private void createGrid(List<App> appList) {

        if(appGridView!=null){
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(appGridView).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        appGridView = new AppGridView();


        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_top_app_grid, appGridView).commitAllowingStateLoss();}
```

and i also add this to my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        // for bug fixing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        try {
            Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
            childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
            childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but ACRA reports me this crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(SourceFile:1376)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(SourceFile:595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(SourceFile:578)
```

please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: before this error occurs do you navigate from your activity in terms of anything? and do you have no history set on the activity? just asking

Comment: no navigate and no history. ACRA report this crash for me. i have not seen this crash during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i put createGrid in to :

```
if(isadded){
creategrid()
}else{
recreate activity
}
```

the problem solved.